# Display list of only specific tags on product

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, tags

Good afternoon,

I know I'm doing this wrong, looked at all the other questions but can't get it figured out.  I have a tag list with images assigned that are displayed in a separate area of my site. I don't want to display all the tags assigned to the product, only the specific tags; they are TAG1, TAG2, and TAG3.  I attempted to put the below <<< >>> in to see if it would work but to no avail. My best guess is I need to create an array to put the tag names in and inject them into the loop a different way.

Thanks in advance

```
    public function shortcode_custom_tags() {
    if ( is_product() || is_shop() ) {

        ob_start();

    
        global $product;
        //var_dump($product);
        $product_tags = get_the_terms( $product->get_id(), 'product_tag' );

        if ( ! is_array( $product_tags ) ) {
            return $product_tags;

        }
        ?>
    <div class="img-listings">
        <label style="font-weight: bold; font-size: 16px;">Works with</label>
        <ul>
            <?php
            foreach ( $product_tags as $product_tag ) {
        <<<<<<if ( $product_tag->slug = ["TAG1, "TAG2", "TAG3"]) {>>>>
                $img_url = get_option( 'z_taxonomy_image' . $product_tag->term_id );

                $this->format_setting( $product_tag->name, $img_url, $product_tag->term_id );
            <<<}>>>
            }
            ?>
        </ul></div>
            <?php
    } else {
        return;
    }
    return ob_get_clean();
}
```

Comment: Your PHP syntax is incorrect - you are reassigning `$product->slug` to the value `["TAG1", "TAG2", "TAG3"]`. To check if a value is in an array, use [`in_array()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php). As this question seems to be about PHP rather than WordPress or it's APIs, it may be closed as off-topic for this stack.

Answer (score 0):

First: you're using `=` which [assigns a value](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.assignment.php); use `==` to [compare the values](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php) (or `===` to compare strictly, ie, match both the value *and* the type).

Second: Your code snippet shows that you've mismatched the `"`s in the array, which should probably result in a PHP fatal error. I'm assuming that's an error in the posted code but not in your production code.

Finally: your comparison will only work if `$product_tag->slug` matches the entire array shown. If you only want to check if `$product_tag->slug` matches one of the items in the array, you'll need to use [`in_array()`](https://www.php.net/in_array).

eg:

```
if ( in_array( $product_tag->slug, ["TAG1", "TAG2", "TAG3"] ) ) {
    $img_url = get_option( 'z_taxonomy_image' . $product_tag->term_id );

    $this->format_setting( $product_tag->name, $img_url, $product_tag->term_id );
}
```